Attempt to invoke interface method 'void Hc.x.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
This is my ViweModel. I'm using hilt for injectin api service.
@HiltViewModel
  class HomePageViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val bannerVideosServiceFactory: BannerVideosService.AssistedFactory
) : ViewModel() {

   init {
       getBannerVideos()
   }

    private val _bannerVideos =
    MutableStateFlow<Resource<List<ContentInfo?>>>(Resource.Loading)
    val bannerVideos = _bannerVideos.asStateFlow()

        private fun getBannerVideos() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val response = bannerVideosServiceFactory.create(
                ContentVideosRequestParams("NULL", 0, 0)
            ).loadData()
            _bannerVideos.value = Success(response)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            context.showToast(e.message ?: "Error")
        }
      }
    }

This is the error that I'm facing right now.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void 
Hc.x.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference com.nex.tsports.ui.home.HomePageViewModel$getBannerVideos$1.invokeSuspend(HomePageViewModel.kt:80)

I could not able to identify the error.

Please [edit] the question to also provide BannerVideosService, ContentVideosRequestParams and Resource and everything they depend on so we can execute your code - or remove them alltogether if they are not relevant to the issue. Please make sure the code in your question qualifies as a [mre], so make sure that all code you do provide is actually needed for the reproducibility.
